# looping through object in php gives error

Tags: php, foreach

Okay.. I did a lot of research but I kept getting errors so I decided to ask the question directly..
I always converted objects to arrays, but I now want to try using an object directly to save website speed.. I got this object:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [date] => Wed, 8 Feb 2017 15:03:44 +0000
    [Date] => Wed, 8 Feb 2017 15:03:44 +0000
    [subject] => asdasdasd
    [Subject] => asdasdasd
    [message_id] => 
    [toaddress] => "test@hotmail.com" 
    [to] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [personal] => test@hotmail.com
                    [mailbox] => test
                    [host] => hotmail.com
                )

        )

    [fromaddress] => Jason K 
    [from] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [personal] => Jason K
                    [mailbox] => JasonK
                    [host] => hotmail.com
                )

        )

    [reply_toaddress] => Jason K 
    [reply_to] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [personal] => Jason K
                    [mailbox] => JasonK
                    [host] => hotmail.com
                )

        )

    [senderaddress] => Jason K 
    [sender] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [personal] => Jason K
                    [mailbox] => JasonK
                    [host] => hotmail.com
                )

        )

    [Recent] =>  
    [Unseen] =>  
    [Flagged] =>  
    [Answered] =>  
    [Deleted] =>  
    [Draft] =>  
    [Msgno] =>    1
    [MailDate] =>  8-Feb-2017 16:03:25 +0100
    [Size] => 7887
    [udate] => 1486566205
)
```

I am trying to get the first date (wed, 8 feb 2017), the from->mailbox and the Size. I managed to get the from->mailbox with this code:

```
foreach($EmailHeaders->from as $from ){
    echo $from->mailbox;
}
```

But I just cant find out how to obtain the other values aswell.. If i try:

```
foreach($EmailHeaders as $headers){
    echo $headers->date;
}
```

then it doesnt work... Can anyone explain this to me? Sorry if this is already asked a thousand times before, I just cant figure it out..

Comment: `$EmailHeaders` is you object. First you access "from" doing `$EmailHeaders->from`, and then you try to loop of `$EmailHeaders`, and get `date` form a child. This is non sence, just access `$EmailHeaders->date`...

Comment: date is not an array, so you should be able to obtain it like this: `$EmailHeaders->date`

Comment: The key you're trying to access is the direct property of the object you're accessing through. `$EmailHeaders->date` is the right way of accessing the property you want. Hope you get it.

Comment: *"try using an object directly to save website speed"* -- `stdClass` is just an array with a fancy syntax for access. Anyway, if you don't handle millions of objects (or arrays) in a single request then you should focus on other components (database, file system, external APIs, email sending) for speed improvements.

Answer (score 0):

check this http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php

```
var_dump(get_object_vars($EmailHeaders ));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, you don't have to iterate over the direct properties, just use

```
$EmailHeaders->date
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the "date", you just need to use $EmailHeaders->date
You don't need a foreach. It's working for "from" because it contains an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

```
$EmailHeaders->date
```

OR

```
$EmailHeaders->Date
```

to get the date from your object.
While iterating through loop, your pointer is already on the date item, so you can't point to date index. It will point to the date index under date item.